# Could I export class names and package names into csv file? (java)

Tags: java, architecture, export

I have one java project in netBeans. There are some packages, and classes in that packages. Can I export this structure to csv?

Example of csv:

myPackage1,MyClass1;

myPackage1,MyClass2;

I would be more pleased if I can put parameters in constructors or voids into that csv.

Thank you for ideas.

EDIT: If there are applications that are able to do reverse engineering to class diagram, there must be some easy way how to do it.

Comment: Could you better explain what you mean by the parameters/constructors thing?

Comment: I think OP wants to list package, class and initilizers in a three parameter csv file. Something like `com.myglorious.package, FooClass, FooClass(Bar bar, RTFM rtfm)`

Comment: yes, in my example would be couple more columns. If class have one constructor with int and String param, there would be ..., int, String

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA Yes, exactly that I mean. Even better would be if there can be another columns for voids in the same way like your example of constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a directory walker algorithm that goes through and finds .java or .class files and adds them to a list of lists (which would be your csv file). If you wanted to add in parameters then you could open the class file, use reflection to see if you can find any constructors and add them as you see fit.

Here try this:

(LOAD)
Assume that your package is a directory (which it is). You will want to walk the
directory looking for all nested .java or .class files and directories. You will
want to either open the java file or load (using the ClassLoader) the class file.

Now from here we will have to branch our algorithm.

(.CLASS BRANCH)
If it is a class file, then you already have all the methods you will need. Use
the java.reflect pacakge you reflectively find the constuctors of the class. Jump
to CREATE CSV.

(.JAVA BRANCH)
However, if it is a java file, then you will have a much harder time. You will
need to create a parser (or find one) that will be able to search for your
constructors and all the other data you want. Then just run all the java files you
through your parser and jump to CREATE CSV

(CREATE CSV)
Now from here you just format the csv file. Take the current directory you are in,
which coincidentally is your package name,  paste that into the csv file along with
all the class data you want from the .CLASS BRANCH and the .JAVA BRANCH

Comment: can you give me some link where it is explained? I think I do not understand you (i am not native speaker)

Answer (score 2):

This may sound over simplified, but what I would do is just move to the folder of your porject in the terminal and execute "tree". It would giva a nice start for find/replace actins. Apart from that, I have no clue on how do do such a thing.

Comment: yes, maybee it is good way how to start. Then I should do some parser by which I can extract voids and constructors from *.class files. It seems quite difficult.

Comment: @John You don't need a parser. This can all be done reflectively.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA can you send some link with explanation please?

Comment: @John Take a look at this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Answer (score 1):

(You could clarify your question a little more. What is the real problem?)

1. You can use reflection to check class detail and write to a csv file
2. If you want analyse the source code and do some quick reporting use [javaparser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/).
3. Without reflection:  use some bytecode engineeting tool like ASM/ BCEL to inspect .class file and extract info you need.